# which css3 selector to use to select last child element on hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors

is it possible, to do something like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Something</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Something</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Something</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Whereby, when I hover on any of the 'li' tags, the 'p' tag is affected. I know I can affect the 'span' in the example with the following:

```
li:hover span{
    /* Whatever css that is needed */
}
```

I'm thinking of something with nth child, am I going the right way with that thought?

```
div li:hover <some nth child syntax that I don't know>{
    /* Whatever css that is needed */
}
```

Or I'm open to any other ideas, so long as they're strictly css... :-) Don't worry about browser cross compatibility either...

Comment: FYI, you didn't close your `<ul>` properly. I've fixed it for you

Comment: Thanks mate, got hasty trying to get the question out I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the kinda thing you're after is jQuery's [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector. Unfortunately, this isn't part of any CSS spec.

That would be used like this: `div:has(li:hover) > p`.

In standard CSS though, I don't think it it's possible.

---

If you're content to style the p when any part of the `ul` is hovered (which includes it's children, then this will work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YCHpd/)):

```
ul:hover + p {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ah, good enough mate... This appear to serve the purpose, and should do good... If you can, could you please explain the selector and the syntax you've used here?

Comment: @Abhishek: Top or bottom one? Bottom one is the adjacent sibling selector: `A + B` selects all `B`s that are immediately preceded by an `A`. `A` and `B` can be any valid selector, I think

Comment: The bottom one mate... From what I gather, you're basically stating that when the 'ul' elementis hovered, affect the 'p' element that follows the 'ul' immediately... Correct?